# Is it possible to access a windows network or local drive from a remote Jupyter Notebook server running on Linux?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a web address that brings me to a remote Jupyter Notebook (Linux) server that I access from my Windows machine but need access to data on a local drive.

I have tried ssh and changing the config file, as well as changing the directory command but keep getting no location found

Answer (score 0):

You can use file upload widget from `ipywidgets` to interact with your local storage via browser client. More info in [ipywidgets docs](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#File-Upload).
You need to upload and write to the server.